# How to display smooth video in FireMonkey (FMX, FM3)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, video, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm3

Has anyone figured out how to display smooth video (i.e. a series of bitmaps) in a FireMonkey application, HD or 3D? In VCL you could write to a canvas from a thread and this would work perfectly, but this does not work in FMX. To make things worse, the apparently only reliable way is to use TImage, and that seems to be updated from the main thread (open a menu and video freezes temporarily). All EMB examples I could find all either write to TImage from the main thread, or use Synchronize(). These limitations make FMX unusable for decent video display so I am looking for a hack or possibly bypass of FMX. I use XE5/C++ but welcome any suggestions. Target OS is both Windows 7+ & OS X. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is in fact possible as TMediaPlayer does not exhibit the same problems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research, including some talks with the [Itinerant developer](http://itinerantdeveloper.blogspot.nl/), has unfortunately made it clear that, due to concurrency restrictions, FM has been designed so that all GPU access goes through the main thread and therefore painting will always be limited. As a result I have decided FM is not suitable for my needs and I am re-evaluating my options.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a TPaintbox on your form to hold the video. In the OnPaint method you simply draw the next frame to the paintbox canvas.  Now put a TTimer on the form, set the interval to the frame rate required. In the OnTimer event for the timer just write paintbox1.repaint

This should give you regular frames no matter what else the program is doing.

For extra safety, you could increment a frame number in the OnTimer event. Now in the paintbox paint method you know which frame to paint. This means you won't jump frames if something else calls the paint method as well as the timer - you will just end up repainting the same frame for the extra call to OnPaint.

I use this for marching ants selections although I go one step further and use an overlaid canvas so I can draw independently to the selection and the underlying paintbox canvas to remove the need to repaint the main canvas when the selection changes. That requires calls to API but I guess you won't need it unless you are doing videos with a transparent colour.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix the problem. Whether you use TImage or a Canvas's OnPaint, you're still being limited by the main thread.

Comment: On windows you can get the device context and then use windows API commands to draw to it thus bypassing the Firemonkey painting. For example getdc(FmxHandleToHWND(form1.Handle)) will get you the device context for form1. You will need fmx.platform.win in the uses statement.Unfortunately the OSX equivalent of a DC is only valid in the paint method so I don't know of any way to bypass firemonkey on OSX.

Comment: The whole reason the use FM is to get accelerated GPU painting, bypassing, if at all possible, would negate the reason to use it.